# Batch File with User Input, Rename and Copy to a different Location

Tags: variables, batch-file

I have a large amount of files to Rename based on User input variable and then copy to a specific location.  Below is a sample of what I have thus far.  It appears as though the Set /p is recognized in the Rename command by not when it goes to Copy it to the new dir.   Any help would be appreciated.

```
 @Echo OFF
 Echo "Blahhh  Rename and Copy.  Press Enter."
 Pause

 SET /p SN=EnterServerName-  
 Echo You Entered - %SN% 
 Pause  

 Rename C:\ctemp\WorkingCSRs\key.pem %SN%_Key.bin

 Copy C:\ctemp\WorkingCSRs\Certificates\%SN%_Key.bin  C:\ctemp\WorkingCSRs\Certificates\folder /y
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're renaming in `C:\ctemp\WorkingCSRs`, but the renamed file is expected to be in `C:\ctemp\WorkingCSRs\Certificates` when copying.

Also you could do the copy as (assuming you don't need the file to be renamed):

```
Copy C:\ctemp\WorkingCSRs\key.pem C:\ctemp\WorkingCSRs\Certificates\folder\%SN%_Key.bin /y
```

Comment: Thanks I feel like a big dummy.  Looking at at it to long I guess, I do have to rename based on user input.